# I need to bound from query row to a label.text

Tags: sql-server, text, label

Please look at code below and help me with your experience. I need to pull out company name from query and bound it to the lblCustName.text I tried different method but still I am getting errors. Please help to fix this problem.

```
public partial class frmMTO : Form
{
    static string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cfTrack.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString;
    DataTable mtotbl = new DataTable("tbl");

    public frmMTO()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  private void frmMTO_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStart.Enabled = false;
        lblCustName.Text = "";
      // Binding data to Customers List  
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Quote_No, Company FROM tblRFQ_logs ORDER BY Quote_No DESC", con);
        DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);


        cmRFQ.ValueMember = "id";
        cmRFQ.DisplayMember = "Quote_No";
        cmRFQ.DataSource = dt;


        SqlDataAdapter materiaDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Grade FROM tblMaterialGrades", con);
        DataTable materialDT = new System.Data.DataTable();
        materiaDA.Fill(materialDT);

        cmMaterial.ValueMember = "Grade_id";
        cmMaterial.DisplayMember = "Grade";
        cmMaterial.DataSource = materialDT;


        // Closing Connection
        con.Close();


        mtotbl.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        mtotbl.Columns.Add("Material", typeof(string));
        mtotbl.Columns.Add("Item Mark", typeof(string));
        mtotbl.Columns.Add("Short Code", typeof(string));
        mtotbl.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        mtotbl.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));
        mtotbl.Columns.Add("QTY.", typeof(string));

        mtotbl.Rows.Add(1, "SA-106 B", "N1", "PIP4STD106","4in STD SA-106B, SMLS", "in.", "6");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = mtotbl;
    }
private void cmRFQ_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // here I need to change the label text
lblCustName.Text = "Company" <------ this data comes from query
    }
```

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you bind the selected index change to this function.

```
cmRFQ.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(list_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
protected void list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList list = (DropDownList)sender;
        string value = (string)list.SelectedValue;
        lblCustName.Text = value
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Application is Windows form. I modified your solution but it didn't work.